# Failed parsing Thymeleaf template when validating form with Spring Bean Validation API

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, bean-validation

I am following this book "Spring In Action 5th Edition" example, but having this error whenever validation on form input found something invalid.

error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Oct 27 17:26:07 SGT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/design.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/design.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "design" - line 59, col 20)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "design" - line 59, col 20)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'design' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    ... 67 more
```

Object been passed to view template:

```
package tacos;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Taco {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, message="Name must be at least 5 characters long")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, message="You must choose at least 2 ingredient")
    private List<String> ingredients;
}
```

Thymeleaf view template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Taco Cloud</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Design your taco!</h1>
<img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}"/>
<form method="POST" th:object="${design}">
<div class="grid">
<div class="ingredient-group" id="wraps">
<h3>Designate your wrap:</h3>
<div th:each="ingredient : ${wrap}">
<input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"
/>
<span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ingredient-group" id="proteins">
<h3>Pick your protein:</h3>
<div th:each="ingredient : ${protein}">
<input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"
/>
<span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ingredient-group" id="cheeses">
<h3>Choose your cheese:</h3>
<div th:each="ingredient : ${cheese}">
<input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"
/>
<span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
<h3>Determine your veggies:</h3>
<div th:each="ingredient : ${veggies}">
<input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"
/>
<span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ingredient-group" id="sauces">
<h3>Select your sauce:</h3>
<div th:each="ingredient : ${sauce}">
<input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"
/>
<span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3>Name your taco creation:</h3>
<input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
<span class="validationError"
                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
                th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</span>
<br/>
<button>Submit your taco</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller display form method:

```
    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm(Model model)
    {
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
                new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
                new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
                new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN),
                new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN),
                new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES),
                new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES),
                new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE),
                new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE),
                new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE),
                new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE)
                );

        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type : types)
        {
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(), 
                    filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }

        model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());

        return "design";
    }
```

Controller process form method:

```
    @PostMapping
    public String processDesign(@Valid Taco taco, Errors errors)
    {
        if (errors.hasErrors())
        {
            return "design";
        }

        // Save the taco design...
        // We will do this in chapter 3
        log.info("Processing design: " + taco);

        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }
```

I have no issue in displaying the form. All input fields are well received and processed. But whenever there is validation errors, and `process form method` call back to the form page "design", the form  failed to parse with above mentioned errors.
I had tried:
1. to disable validation on the Taco.name field;
2. to remove the `<span>` which displays the name field errors. 
But none of them work.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't see a `th:action`

Comment: Hi @vphilipnyc, form without `th:action` will call back to the same path of request. I have no issue in POST request the form to my controller for form input validation. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Have you tried annotating your post method a model attribute like `@ModelAttribute("design") Taco taco`?

Answer (score 2):

I try change this code

```
@PostMapping
public String processDesign(@Valid Taco taco, Errors errors)
{
    if (errors.hasErrors())
    {
        return "design";
    }

    // Save the taco design...
    // We will do this in chapter 3
    log.info("Processing design: " + taco);

    return "redirect:/orders/current";
}
```

to

```
@PostMapping
public String processDesign(@Valid Taco taco, Errors errors)
{
    if (errors.hasErrors())
    {
        return "redirect:/design";
    }

    // Save the taco design...
    // We will do this in chapter 3
    log.info("Processing design: " + taco);

    return "redirect:/orders/current";
}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. This is what I did to fix it.

1st - change the opening header in design.html to the following

```
<form method="POST" th:object="${design}">
```

2nd - my processDesign() method looks like this:

```
public String processDesign(@Valid @ModelAttribute("design") Taco taco, Errors errors) {

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "design";
    }

    // this will save our Taco Design
    // log.info("Processing design: " + design);

    return "redirect:/orders/current";
}
```

I hope, that this helps and I'm not too late. In general, there are multiple similar errors in the book, that need to be fixed, but the community around it is great, so no need to worry.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The code in book has some error, here is the right code from the github of book:

```
// tag::head[]
package tacos.web;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import tacos.Ingredient;
import tacos.Ingredient.Type;
import tacos.Taco;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignTacoController {

//end::head[]

@ModelAttribute
public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
      new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
      new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
      new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN),
      new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN),
      new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES),
      new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES),
      new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE),
      new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE),
      new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE),
      new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE)
    );

    Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
    for (Type type : types) {
      model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
          filterByType(ingredients, type));
    }
}

//tag::showDesignForm[]
  @GetMapping
  public String showDesignForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());
    return "design";
  }

//end::showDesignForm[]

/*
//tag::processDesign[]
  @PostMapping
  public String processDesign(Design design) {
    // Save the taco design...
    // We'll do this in chapter 3
    log.info("Processing design: " + design);

    return "redirect:/orders/current";
  }

//end::processDesign[]
 */

//tag::processDesignValidated[]
  @PostMapping
  public String processDesign(@Valid @ModelAttribute("design") Taco design, Errors errors, Model model) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      return "design";
    }

    // Save the taco design...
    // We'll do this in chapter 3
    log.info("Processing design: " + design);

    return "redirect:/orders/current";
  }

//end::processDesignValidated[]

//tag::filterByType[]
  private List<Ingredient> filterByType(
      List<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {
    return ingredients
              .stream()
              .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

//end::filterByType[]
// tag::foot[]
}
// end::foot[]
```

### and you can get all the source code from https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples

ps: In my opinion, the possible reason is that `@valide Taco` will transport a Taco object named `taco` to the template, while we use the `design` in the tempalte, so, the template cannot find the `design` which result in the error. And `@ModelAttribute('design')` can renamed the `Taco` object to `design`. On the other hand, we need the ingredients list to init the template whenever we visit the tacoDesign html, that is the reason that we separate the  `addIngredientsToModel` method and using `@ModelAttribute` above it.